# Talking to a motor driver through USB

Tags: usb, can-bus, motordriver

I have a motor, connected to a motor driver, connected a windows XP computer by a CAN-BUS (throught USB). I want to "talk" to the motor driver and have some questions:

- Does the USB appear as a COM port?
- What protocol do I use or how do I
  find out what protocol to use?
- Does anyone have or know of any
  public implementations of a similar
  thing that I can look at?
- Are there any other hits you want to share?

  Thanks!

Comment: The results of what is learned here may be very relevant to the folks at http://autos.stackexchange.com !

Comment: stackoverflow.com might be a good place to try too.  Sounds like it might fall under the realm of a programming question.

Comment: Nono, if this question needs to be on SO we'll migrate it for you!

Answer (score 1):

While I also think SO is a better place for this, I do have some useful information.

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HIDAche.aspx) CodeProject article, it explains the basics of talking to USB devices, with a sample Win32 application.  It's pretty focused on the HID class of USB devices, so if you CAN based driver doesn't present itself as a HID device, you might be in for some pretty significant work.